# How to fix mangled log rows with formatting in Cloud Watch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm looking at my logs in Cloud Watch and it seems that there is some sort of formattin problem. This is what I see there:

```
[90m2023-02-13 21:07:21.521  [39m[1m[94mINFO[39m[22m  [90m[PrepareNextTransaction dist/apps/admin/.next/server/chunks/813.js:5114  AsyncTask.handler][39m
```

If I run this app locally I can see the same rows properly:

```
2023-02-13 21:10:09.797  INFO  [PrepareNextTransaction   AsyncTask.execute]
```

It seems to me that CloudWatch doesn't understand the formatting, but I don't see a setting to fix this.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

The formatting problem you're encountering in CloudWatch is due to the usage of ANSI escape codes in your log output.

ANSI escape codes are a sequence of characters used to format text in a terminal. For example, the code `\033[31m` can be used to change the text color to red.

However, not all applications that display text, such as CloudWatch, support ANSI escape codes.

It would be best if you investigated how to proper configure your application code output in order to avoid ANSI codes in CloudWatch logs.